# How to set time between calls

Tags: c#

IB has rules that I cannot run more than 6 of these calls in 2 seconds. I have been running into the pacing rules and need to find a work around. Can I save the method call(Historicaldata) as object and call it periodically?
I do have multiple threads that call into this method and need to find a solution to pause between calls to ibClient.ClientSocket.reqHistoricalData for every 6 consecutive calls.

```
private void Historicaldata(int tickerId, Contract contract, string endDateTime,
        string durationString, string barSizeSetting, string whatToShow, int useRTH, int formatDate, List<TagValue> chartOptions)
    {
        ibClient.ClientSocket.reqHistoricalData(tickerId, contract, endDateTime, durationString, barSizeSetting, whatToShow, useRTH, formatDate, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class with a `ConcurrentQueue` to hold your parameters.

When creating the class you can start a timer that fires every 2/6 seconds.

The timer call back can check if there are any items in your queue and if so make your method call.

Alternately you can add delegates to your queue and the timer can invoke the delegates.